# Laravel 5 target is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, ioc-container, laravel-5

Multiple questions already asked about this topic, but I still have this problem and I don't have a clue on what the problem is.

I want to achieve that I can instantiate an interface instead of an implementation.

**I'm using Laravel 5, this is the code/structure:**

In app, I have created a Contracts folder. In this folder I have Messenger.php:

**Messenger.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Contracts;

interface Messenger {

    public function goodmorning($name);

}
```

In app/Services I have
**DailyMessenger.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\Messenger;

class DailyMessenger implements Messenger {

    public function goodmorning($name)
    {
        return 'Goodmorning '. $name;
    }

}
```

Now I want to instantiate the interface in my **controller**:

```
public function __construct(Messenger $messenger)
    {
        $this->messenger = $messenger;
    }
```

Now, if I follow the documentation on the Laravel website I should only have to register this in the service container, which I do in the existing **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
            'App\Services\Registrar'
        );

        $this->app->bind('App\Contacts\Messenger', 'App\Services\DailyMessenger');
    }
```

If I visit appropriate route that maps to the controller I get the error:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 785:
Target [App\Contracts\Messenger] is not instantiable.
```

I think I have followed the Laravel docs precisely but what am I missing? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've spelled the namespace wrong when binding, used App\Contacts instead of App\Contracts.  Should be:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Contracts\Messenger', 'App\Services\DailyMessenger');
```